# Post from WP7 app is an empty array

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-7, post

I have the following code for handling a simple post under WP7:

```
private void goto_login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
   webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml";
   var uri = new Uri("http://example.com/wp_login", UriKind.Absolute);
   StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
   postData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", "username", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username_box.Text));
   postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "password", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password_box.Password));
   webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = postData.Length.ToString();
   webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
   webClient.UploadProgressChanged += webClient_UploadProgressChanged;
   webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", postData.ToString());
}

void webClient_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("result: "+e.Result);
}

void webClient_UploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Progress: {0} ", e.ProgressPercentage));
}
```

On the PHP side, the script simply does this:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Doing this, I always end up with an empty array from the server. If it makes any difference, I'm running it on the emulator instead of a device. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone happens by this question looking for an answer, this was the problem:

```
webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml";
```

Should be changed to:

```
webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```